# The remainingFillableTakerAmount of new sell order is zero on Polygon and it lasts a long time

Tags: 0x

When I sell a order successfully on Polygon, the remainingFillableTakerAmount is zero and it lasts a long time before remainingFillableTakerAmount return to normal value. Now, I can not find the reason, can anyone help me to solve the problem, thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more context? Where and how are you seeing `remainingFillableTakerAmount`?

Comment: OK, It occurs when I sell a order on public relayer for a new option product. After I  wait for several hours, the remainingFillableTakerAmount is normal.

Comment: Are you seeing it on their frontend? Perhaps it's an issue with them?